How do I implement a function to replace C comments from // to /* */ (in uppercase)?
I am trying to write a function to replace comments in C using:
// Comment
into
/* COMMENT */.
This is what I have tried:
function! ANSIC89()
    :%s/\/\/\(.*\)/\/\* \1 \*\//g
endfunction


This replaces:
  7 // Dataset Structure 
  8 typedef struct {
  9     int num_bars;            // Number of bars
 10     int *data;               // Data array
 11     int *x_values;           // X positions of bars 
 12     unsigned long color;     // Bar color 
 13 } Dataset;

Into:
  7 /* Dataset Structure  */
  8 typedef struct {
  9     int num_bars;            /* Number of bars */
 10     int *data;               /* Data array */
 11     int *x_values;           /* X positions of bars  */
 12     unsigned long color;     /* Bar color  */
 13 } Dataset;

But I do not know how to make them uppercase (I am not sure if this can be actually done with regex at all).

You escape slashes in the search part but have forgotten to escape them in replace part. To simplify your expression use a different search characters like ! or @: %s!^//\s\+\(.\+\)!/* \1 */!

Thanks, modified with a corrected version, I still do not know how to make them uppercase

See :help sub-replace-special.

Unrelated to your question, but C99 is ANSI and allows C++-style comments.

Thanks. Edited function name to ANSIC89

... because who would like to use a 25 year old standard if you can also use a 35 year old one? :-D

My middle name is legacy

Building on M.E.'s answer, there are some points for simplifications and improvements that are beyond the scope (and restrictions) of comments.
The :substitute command can be further simplified to
:%s@//\s*\(.*\)@/* \U\1 */@

which uses @ as separator and cuts off any kind of whitespace (space and tabs) using the \s pattern. The comments contents itself is captured using a simple greedy match all .* .
If you want the result to be really beautiful and make sure there's exactly one space between comment and the closing */, you can use the slightly more complicated
:%s@//\s*\(.\{-}\)\s*$@/* \U\1 */@

This captures non-greedily using the \{-} multi. It is followed by any number of whitespace \s*, anchored to the end of line $.
All of the above is explained in :help pattern.
There's a user-defined function in the question and unless there's a good reason to use one, I'd suggest to use a mapping or a user-defined command.
A simple one-liner rarely warrants a function.
Instead, map e.g. your F2 key:
:nnoremap <buffer> <F2> :%s@//\s*\(.\{-}\)\s*$@/* \U\1 */@<CR>

Or define a user-command you can call with :ANSIC89:
:command -buffer -bar -range=% ANSIC89 <line1>,<line2>s@//\s*\(.\{-}\)\s*$@/* \U\1 */@

The above will work on a range of lines, defaulting to the whole buffer. See :help :command-range.
The -bar argument allows to follow with another command, e.g. :ANSIC89 | write.
See :help user-commands for reference.
Both the mapping and the command are defined as buffer-local so they exist only when editing C files. You can put them in ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/c.vim.

With the hints and help received:
function! ANSIC89()
    :%s/\/\/ *\([^ ].*\)/\/\* \U\1 \*\//g
endfunction

This allows to handle comments where there are more than one space after // characters.

That's a lot of leaning toothpicks. You should have gone with phd's suggestion of using non-/ as a delimiter.

I tried without success, what would be the equivalent?

That would be :%s@// *\([^ ].*\)@/* \U\1 */@ with @ as separator (any non-alnum will do). You don't need to escape * in the replacement string and you also don't need the g flag.
